# Silverlight Listbox custom style

Tags: silverlight, listbox, contentcontrol

I have defined a style in my resource file like below

```
   <Style x:Name="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">                    
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               Margin="5" 
                               Foreground="Red">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               Margin="5">
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>    
</Style>
```

I am at a loss as to what to put here within the data template

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I tried using

```
<ContentPresenter Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}"></ContentPresenter>
```

and even

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}"></ContentControl>`
```

but got this error

> Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style'.

What do I put in between the `DataTemplate` tags if I want to provide a custom style?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? You have defined a style for `ListBox` and you are trying to apply it on `ContentPresenter` and `ContentControl`. That is not right.

Comment: I want to define the style for the listbox in another resource file and in my page.xaml just refer to that style. What is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               Margin="5" 
                               Foreground="Red">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               Margin="5">
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This shpuld solve your problem.

If you define a style, you define how the ListBox looks like (Background, Foreground, ...).
You can get the default style here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx

The ItemTemplate (it is a DataTemplate) defines, how a the data presentation of a single element of the list looks like (You use bindings and so on...).

If you want to define a style for the single elements, like MouseOver, Focussed, ... you write a style for the ListBoxItems. You can add it to the list box via ItemContainerStyle.

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource YourResourceKey}"/>
```